# bluetooth4.0 ble receive sms notification

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, sms, core-bluetooth

I found SMS notifications are not supported in iPhone,but I found cookoo watch and meta watch have realized it.they are based on bluetooth4.0(BLE),i'm writing an app like them,i have already realized income call alert. could you help me？

Answer (score 0):

You can't get an app to connect the devices its bluetooth stack and receive the SMS alert.

Answer (score 0):

I think cookoo is using a classic bluetooth stack + ble4.0... and for sms / call notification they are NOT using ble4 but basic ble2 or 3 stack...